# jQuery - User name & Password matches then enable submit button

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery login...

By default I am disabling "Submit" button. It will only enable if Email id matches to `info@company.com` and password matches to `hello`

But, as soon as I enter the correct email id and tab out, submit button is getting enabled.

**I want to enable "submit" button only when User name and Password is entered correctly**

> **[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nc6NW/257/)**

**jQuery**

```
$('#validateUser input').keyup(function() {
  var userEmail = $('#userEmail').val();
  var userPassword = $('#userPassword').val();
  if( userEmail !== 'info@company.com' && userPassword !== 'hello') {
    $('#loginSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#loginSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="dashboard.html" id="validateUser">
    <div><input type="text" id='userEmail' placeholder="Email ID"></div>
    <div><input type="password" id='userPassword' placeholder="Password"></div>
    <button type="submit" id="loginSubmit" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You are of course aware that it is highly useless to include username and password on the client?

Comment: It is bad practice to hardcode username and password but sometime there are demo websites which doesn't need to be super secured so some developers prefer to go this way so that they can distribute standard username password to their clients.

Comment: **@Mihir Solank** You are on the spot... yes, it is for Online Demo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is:

> Disable if username is nor correct ***and*** password is not correct.

You want your condition to be:

> Disable if username is nor correct ***or*** password is not correct.

You can do this two ways, minimum change is to change the *and* to an *or*:

your code:

```
if (userEmail !== 'info@company.com' && userPassword !== 'hello') {
    $('#loginSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
} else {
    $('#loginSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

should be:

```
if (userEmail !== 'info@company.com' || userPassword !== 'hello') {
    $('#loginSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
} else {
    $('#loginSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

or you can change the 'not equal or not equal' to 'equal and equal' but also change around the if/else code.

```
if (userEmail === 'info@company.com' && userPassword === 'hello') {
    $('#loginSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
} else {
    $('#loginSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

(note removeAttr/attr swapped)

This says:

> Enable if username and password are correct

Comment: **@freedomn-m** Thanks for the clarification... and smart answers.. I am Upvoting your answer and Accepting... Keep up the great work

Comment: @Reddy It's recommended to use [jQuery.prop](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of attr for setting the disabled property. You could therefore replace the if statement above with a one liner to set whether the submit button is disabled: `$('#loginSubmit').prop('disabled', userEmail !== 'info@company.com' || userPassword !== 'hello')`

Answer (score 3):

Simple.

```
  if( userEmail === 'info@company.com' && userPassword === 'hello') {
    $('#loginSubmit').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#loginSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
  }
```

Comment: second one will be true , not false

Answer (score 2):

Change your condition as below

```
if( userEmail == 'info@company.com' && userPassword == 'hello') {
    $('#loginSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('#loginSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
  }
```

This code assume that button is disabled by default. If its not disabled by default then please do disable on document load or add disabled attribute

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#validateUser input').keyup(function() {
  var userEmail = $('#userEmail').val();
  var userPassword = $('#userPassword').val();
  if( userEmail == 'info@company.com' && userPassword == 'hello') {
    $('#loginSubmit').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#loginSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Paste following code

```
$('#validateUser input').keyup(function() {
  var userEmail = $('#userEmail').val();
  var userPassword = $('#userPassword').val();
  if( userEmail == 'info@company.com' && userPassword == 'hello') {
    $('#loginSubmit').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
   $('#loginSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try Below**

Your jquery code is almost working. only one small change require. 
in if condition..
like below

```
$('#validateUser input').keyup(function() {
  var userEmail = $('#userEmail').val();
  var userPassword = $('#userPassword').val();
  if( userEmail == 'info@company.com' && userPassword == 'hello') {
   $('#loginSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
   $('#loginSubmit').attr('disabled', true);

  }
});
```

I hope it will work for u. you need to fouse on small things.

Comment: Yes **@Nitesh Pawar** I agree with you... I am using your code... Thanks